# gRPC support for Windows on ARM for HoloLens 2

Tags: c#, windows, arm, grpc, hololens

I want to build my Unity-AR Apps to run on HoloLens 2. We use gRPC for interprocess communication of the HoloLens device and a desktop PC to pass information.
HoloLens 2 has an ARM processor architecture, for which gRPC does not provide a grpc_csharp_ext.dll.

Does anyone already had the same problem and how did you solve it?

*Edit: I use Unity for app development, so I'm limited to .NET Framework & .NET Standard solutions

Comment: gRPC has a C# implementation that should run on .NET core. .NET core apps run on ARM architectures.

Comment: Sorry I did not mention, I use Unity for development and it only supports .NET Standard & Framework

Comment: How do you want to run it on ARM then? .NET Framework does not run on ARM (except if you use mono).

Comment: Yes in Unity you have to steps in your build process: At first Mono compiles your C# scripts to natice C++ code, and then this gets build for your specific arvhitecture (in my case arm) so it should be possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know unity. And there's certainly no C++ involved here, what you mean is machine code. Doesn't matter tough, you can rather think of mono being an interpreter. But yes, mono can run C# on ARM, but I don't know whether it can run unity (since that requires a bunch of other dependencies as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a merged copy/paste from my comments in the grpc issue tracker [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/20344) and [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/23488)

**Edit: I published a Unity project with precompiled libraries for `x86`, `x64` and `arm64` on [Github](https://github.com/OpenAvikom/mr-grpc-unity).**

My workaround for this problem involves compiling a Grpc.Core.dll without the Mono and DllImportsFromStaticLib which is used for WSA builds AND an ARM64 version of the `grpc_charp_ext.dll` which isn't part of the official Unity package but necessary for HoloLens 2.

- Download a daily build unity package (e.g. [this](https://packages.grpc.io/archive/2019/10/8853754e8caa0b2ffb3ab0e25514f3f7612ebf7a-d6090f79-7b70-429d-a477-9df736e4941a/index.xml) one) and unzip it. This is version 1.25-dev. I have tried more recent 1.26-dev daily builds but unfortunately `grpc_charp_ext.dll` is not correctly loaded in the HoloLens emulator for these builds. I also tried the most recent version (1.29.1) vcpkg has to offer but unfortunately there is a Protobuf/System.Memory version conflict ([#22251](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/22251)) which hasnt been resolved yet, afaik.
- clone grpc and checkout the daily build commit:

  - `git checkout 8853754e8caa0b2ffb3ab0e25514f3f7612ebf7a` if you use the build above
- init submodules: `git submodule update --init`
- If you are like me and don't want to install outdated build tools you can change the used Visual Studio version in tools\run_tests\helper_scripts\pre_build_csharp.bat. I used "Visual Studio 15 2017" instead of "Visual Studio 14 2015".
- build `grpc_charp_ext`:

  - `python tools/run_tests/run_tests.py -l csharp -c opt --build_only`
- If everything works well, you will end up with some Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.targets exceptions when the Python script attempts to build the C# project. It's probably related to some outdated SourceLink dependency or something. Nevertheless, the project will build just fine with Visual Studio 2019.
- Apply [grpc-no-static.patch.txt](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/files/3921123/grpc-no-static.patch.txt)
- Open Grpc.sln and compile a Release build
- Copy the resulting Grpc.Core.dll into Plugins/Grcp.Core/lib/net45_wsa of the downloaded package

---

- If you followed these steps, you should have something that works with Unity and HoloLens 1, now the part that makes it work with HoloLens2.
- Clone vcpkg and checkout the tag 2020.01. I don't know whether checking out 2020.01 is actually necessary but it contains the grpc version closest to 1.25

  - `git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg.git`
  - `git checkout 2020.01`
- You have to edit the `grpc` port to build the correct version. Download [00001-fix-uwp.patch.txt](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/files/5200461/00001-fix-uwp.patch.txt), [00002-static-linking-in-linux.patch.txt](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/files/5200462/00002-static-linking-in-linux.patch.txt) and [portfile.cmake.txt](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/files/5200464/portfile.cmake.txt), remove the `.txt` ending and override the files located at `ports\grpc`.
- Copy the Plugins folder into your Unity project
- Make sure that Grpc.Core.dll in the folder net45_wsa is only used for WSA builds and the original build EXCLUDES Grpc.Core.dll in net45_wsa:

[image: Grpc Core_wsa]

- Make sure that grpc_charp_ext in Grpc.Core/runtimes/win/x86 and x64 is exported correctly (correct arch) for WSA:

[image: grpc_cscharp_ext]

- Next you have to backport a triplet configuration: Download [arm64-windows-static.cmake.txt](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/files/5200503/arm64-windows-static.cmake.txt), rename it and put it into `triplets\community`
- Now bootstrap `vcpkg` and build `protobuf:x86-windows` and `grpc` with the `arm64-windows-static` triplet

  - `.\vcpkg.exe install protobuf:x86-windows`
  - `.\vcpkg.exe install grpc --triplet arm64-windows-static`
- Copy the generated file `buildtrees\grpc\arm64-windows-static-rel\grpc_csharp_ext.dll` into your Plugin folder (`Grpc.Core\runtimes\win\arm64`) and set the target for this DLL:
  [image: arm64_ext]
- Export and build your project